# Boost zeta function

Tags: function, math, boost

I try to use zeta function from boost library:

```
double dz1 = boost::math::zeta<double> (1.0);
```

And when I run the program I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::domain_error> >'
what():  Error in function boost::math::zeta<e>: Evaluation of zeta function at pole 1
Aborted (core dumped)'
```

Someone know what is going on?

Comment: The zeta function has a pole at 1, that's what the error message says :)

Comment: This question has been properly answered, but I find it bothersome that `boost::math::zeta` is throwing instead of raising invalid, returning NaN and leaving the handling to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riemann zeta function is an infinite sum:

[image]

It converges only if the real part of the argument is more, then 1. If it is equal to 1, the series diverge and the sum gives infinity.

So the library threw an error, when you called the function with 1.0.

Useful links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/zetas/zeta.html